# ProgressDialog is not closing with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-wifi, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using **BroadcatReceiver** to monitor *wi-fi* state changes.

And I want to show **ProgressDialog** during the operation.

It is showing properly but not closing.

My code is like below::

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
        {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state)
            {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_OFF");
                showProgress(false);
                // showToast("Bluetooth off");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_TURNING_OFF");
                showProgress(true);
                // showToast("Turning Bluetooth off...");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_ON");
                showProgress(false);
                // showToast("Bluetooth on");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_TURNING_ON");
                showProgress(true);
                // showToast("Turning Bluetooth on...");

                break;
            }
        }
    }
};


public void showProgress(boolean show)
{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShortcutActivity.this);

    mProgressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.settings_msg));
    if (show)
    {
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG, " " + mProgressDialog.isShowing());
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}`
```

Please suggest me for solution if my implementation contains any thing wrong.
Or my way of implementation was wrong.

Comment: Show `showProgress` method

Comment: In your showProgress-method a new Progressdialog will be created each time you call it. You have to dismiss the existing ProgressDialog (the one that is currently shown), not the newly created one.

Comment: You are creating new instance of **ProgressDialog** every time so it won't close the previously initiated **ProgressDialog**.

Comment: You have to create a **listener** which can have a callback method which will close the dialog.

Comment: ProgressDialog  are created only one time.. this is created in onCreate and use in ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make the below as global variable

   ```
   ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
   ```
2. OnCreate()

   ```
   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShortcutActivity.this);
   mProgressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.settings_msg));
   ```

3.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
    {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (state)
        {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_OFF");
            showProgress(false);
            // showToast("Bluetooth off");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_TURNING_OFF");
            showProgress(true);
            // showToast("Turning Bluetooth off...");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_ON");
            showProgress(false);
            // showToast("Bluetooth on");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_TURNING_ON");
            showProgress(true);
            // showToast("Turning Bluetooth on...");

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

};

4.

```
 public void showProgress(boolean show)
  {

if (show)
{
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        mProgressDialog.show();
}
else
{
    Log.i(TAG, " " + mProgressDialog.isShowing());
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
    {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your showProgress-method a new Progressdialog will be created each time you call it. You have to dismiss the existing ProgressDialog (the one that is currently shown), not the newly created one.

that right。

Answer (score 0):

I created 
`ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;` at outside and initiated it in `onCreate()` as

`mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShortcutActivity.this);`. Now it's working fine.

Thanks you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare mProgressDialog outside your "showProgress" method and inside showProgress method, initialize mProgressDialog if it is null

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
        {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state)
            {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_OFF");
                showProgress(false);
                // showToast("Bluetooth off");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_TURNING_OFF");
                showProgress(true);
                // showToast("Turning Bluetooth off...");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_ON");
                showProgress(false);
                // showToast("Bluetooth on");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_TURNING_ON");
                showProgress(true);
                // showToast("Turning Bluetooth on...");

                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
public void showProgress(boolean show)
{
    if (mProgressDialog == null)
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShortcutActivity.this);

    mProgressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.settings_msg));
    if (show)
    {
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG, " " + mProgressDialog.isShowing());
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even i need to initiate `mProgressDialog` at outside.